# Which of the following is true about $\mathbb{Q}×[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $\mathbb{Q}×[0,1]$ is  a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology then:

A.  $\mathbb{Q}\times [0,1]$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$

B.  Connected

C.  Separable

D.   Compact

What i have thought is that

(a) It is just a strip, it cannot be dense.

(b) $\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected, hence so is it.

(c) It's neither dense nor countable hence not separable.

(d)  In $\mathbb{R}^2$ by Heine-Borel it is not bounded hence not compact.

I don't know which of my  arguments is wrong. Kindly help!

thanx and regards.

Comment: Look up the definition of "separable".

Comment: @KennyLau  Separable means it's  a countable dense subset right?

Comment: No, that isn't what it means.

Comment: What about rest of my arguments, are they correct??

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Comment: "Separable means it's a countable dense subset right?" No, separable does not mean that it _is_ a countable, dense subset. It means that it _has_ a countable, dense subset.

Comment: @Arthur thnx for the hint , I have given an answer check if it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Basically the correct answer is That it is Separable, 
Which means that it has a countable dense subset which is

Q×Rationals in [0,1] .